Angular CLI installation in Node 22 never completes
I'm using a new M2 MacBook Pro.
I installed Node 22.5.0 as my system Node with Homebrew, and then installed nvm via the install script.
I then installed Node 22 via: nvm install 22
When I use Node 22 and run npm i -g @angular/cli the installation never completes. I've let it run for 30+ minutes. There are no error messages or progress feedback messages.
The same process works as expected using Node 20 in nvm and it took around 10 seconds.
I have tried installing with sudo, and with the --force option; neither work.
What else can I try to get the CLI tools installed in Node 22?

This is a known bug in node 22.5.0
Please use 22.4.1 until this bug is solved.
See also: Node 22.5.0 started to crash and hangs on different cases

FYI: the new version 22.5.1. is out and you can switch back to "22" only...
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager
